# Is it possible to find out Revisions in SVN where in a merge activity was performed

Tags: svn, svn-client

I am trying to find out list of revision on a branch in which a Merge was performed (This could be from any of the branches in SVN)

I have been doing a lot of search and have found ways to identify Revision which were merged and even revision which should be merged (using svn mergeinfo) but that is not what I am looking for.

I want revision in which a merge was performed on  development line for which a URL is passed in as a parameter.
I note that this repository makes use of mergeinfo and I only want to use that.

After hours of search I am finally giving up on this. It seems its either not possible or I am looking in the wrong direction :(

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible out-of-the-box:
Merge activities are recognizable by modification of **svn:mergeinfo** property.

The problem is, you can not see if a change was made in content of a file/directory or if change was made in some properties by looking into the svn log. You need to make a diff between these revisions.

A very easy workaround could be that useres performing a merge operation should add a keyword to log message(for example:*MERGE*). It is quite easy to check via pre-commit hook if the keyword is present in a certain log message

Comment: Doesnt SVN store revision in which this change was made? Not even time of the change?

Comment: Yes it stores it inside a revision, however it is not possible to find revisions which containing the change afterwards..

Comment: Are there any indirect ways of doing this? Maybe using a shell script or something. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use "svnlook diff" but you have to parse every single revision and scan the output for changes in the property